# Randomize or shuffle <ul>items except list items with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have this HTML list `<ul>` which contains list items with two different classes.

```
<ul id="Items">
    <li class="sw">Switchable 1</li>
    <li class="sw">Switchable 2</li>
    <li class="notsw">This should remain 3</li>
    <li class="sw">Switchable 4</li>
    <li class="notsw">This should remain 5</li>
    <li class="sw">Switchable 6</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" class="btn" value="Shuffle" />
```

I am trying to randomize or shuffle the order of the list items when an event is triggered (let's say a button was clicked) but only shuffle the list items with the `.sw` class. So far, I have achieved shuffling the list items(all of them) using a `jQuery` custom function. Then, I tried storing the initial indexes of the `.notsw` list items(I think i'm getting the right values) and used jQuery `.before()` to move it back after the shuffle but still I can't make it go where it should be.

Note: The list items with the .notsw class could be anywhere in the list initially.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var notsws = document.getElementsByClassName("notsw"); 
    var inds = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<notsws.length; i++){
        inds[i] =$('.notsw').eq(i).index();
    }
    $('#Items').randomize();
    for(var k=0; k<notsws.length; k++){
        var curr = inds[k];
        $('.notsw').eq(k).before($('#Items li').eq(curr));
    }
});       


$.fn.randomize = function(selector){
    var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
        $parents = $elems.parent();

    $parents.each(function(){
        $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
        }).remove().appendTo(this);
    });

    return this;
};
```

**[I HAVE A JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mg5B3/9/)**

Comment: A couple questions: 1) will you always be sorting a list of `<li>` tags? 2) will you always wish to exclude tags based on class, or are there other selectors you wish to support?

Comment: @wvandaal I think it will be by classes, the list will be dynamic and the list items with the notsw class can be anywhere in the UL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used an alternate approach. I see that you are randomizing your list and then trying to remember whether the original elements were.

Instead of that, why don't you just shuffle elements based on whether they *can be shuffled*.
In the sense, take an array of the indexes for the `switchable elements` denoted by the selector `.sw` and then shuffle only those indexes.

Here's how the shuffle function would look like.

```
function shuffle(nodes, switchableSelector) {
    var length = nodes.length;

    //Create the array for the random pick.
    var switchable = nodes.filter("." + switchableSelector);
    var switchIndex = [];

    $.each(switchable, function(index, item) {
       switchIndex[index] = $(item).index(); 
    });

    //The array should be used for picking up random elements.
    var switchLength = switchIndex.length;
    var randomPick, randomSwap;

    for (var index = length; index > 0; index--) {
        //Get a random index that contains a switchable element.
        randomPick = switchIndex[Math.floor(Math.random() * switchLength)];

        //Get the next element that needs to be swapped.
        randomSwap = nodes[index - 1];

        //If the element is 'switchable' continue, else ignore
        if($(randomSwap).hasClass(switchableSelector)) {
            nodes[index - 1] = nodes[randomPick];
            nodes[randomPick] = randomSwap;
        }
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

On your button click, you can simply shuffle the nodes and then re-append them to the container.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var $nodes = $("#Items").find("li");
    shuffle($nodes, "sw");
    $("#Items").append($nodes);
});
```

[Working fiddle present here](http://jsfiddle.net/serendipity/Xz6BJ/).

Comment: This is great, thanks :).. Im actually gonna use it in a card game with pin some card and shuffle stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is removing all the `"sw"` elements and then pushing them at the back of the list. I would create a new randomized list with the `"sw"` items and then add the `"notsw"`item at their previous indexes. You should therefore save the `"notsw"` indexes.